# heater is cold until I hear a noise and heat starts immediately

Tags: subaru, hvac, outback

I think the answer to this is easy but I'm not sure of the part name.

I'm driving along and have the heater on, but it's blowing cold air.  Then I hear kind of a "clackety clack", and then the air becomes hot, and I can also see the gauge lowering on the engine temperature.

Seems there is some type of valve which is not opening when it should, but again I am not sure of its name or how to replace it.  It sounds like it's under/behind the dashboard in the center area.  Definitely NOT the engine thermostat, that's under the engine block and not coming from there.

FYI this is a Subaru Outback 2007 but I vaguely recall hearing this noise and situation in other car(s) before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely one of two things. The mode door which opens and closes as more or less heat is requested, is sticking. Or the actuator that opens it is faulty.